# how to use informix unload statement in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, informix, jdbctemplate

I create a TEMP table t1 and wanna write the t1 records to the file with java. I use spring boot with jdbcTemplate and open to use any framework.
I did try the following but no result.

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(("select * from dba.software into TEMP t1;");
jdbcTemplate.execute(("UNLOAD TO /tmp/software.csv DELIMITER '|' SELECT * FROM t1;")
```

**What is the best way to do this using UNLOAD statement?**

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you can't use "LOAD" or "UNLOAD" from anything other than dbaccess or 4GL/ISQL. Both statements are implemented within those tools not in the database engine.

If you want to unload the data to external files using JDBC you will need to fetch it with a cursor and unload it yourself.